# getting error ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. by trying to build

Tags: android, cordova

I get this error with the commane emulate or build despite the .profile's update :

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools"
export ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS="/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools"
export PATH="$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME:$ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS"
```

My emulator is correctly launched (nexus 7) and I installed all the necessary Android packages via the android command.

Answer (score 0):

its suppose to be like this

```
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools
export PATH=${PATH}:/usr/local/android-sdk-linux/tools
```

Comment: Just tried now and it's still doesn't work with this syntax. I follow this tutorial : http://www.levibotelho.com/development/the-complete-guide-to-running-phonegap-on-ubuntu